# How to stop a Javascript animation

Tags: javascript, animation, dom-events

I have this div that listens to mouse clicks, when it receives a mouse click it does some animation, my question is, how can I disable the mouse click event's it receives when until the animation is done?

Comment: Don't disable the mouse-click. Simply disable the *action* the mouse-click would have caused.

Comment: thanks, can't believe i didn't realize that solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check whether the animation is still running in the handler.

For more details, please supply more details.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Grab the object
var obj = document.getElementById('theObject');

// Disable any clicking
obj.onclick = function() { return false; }
```

You can apply the same `.onclick` method when you're ready to use it again.